# Счетчик скачивания файлов на Java (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, такая проблема: есть сайт на бесплатном хостинге Ucoz, они не дают работать с php, а мне нужен счетчик скачивания файлов (подойдет даже счетчик просто кликов по ссылке для скачивания). Можно ставить только скрипты Java (jQuery у них уже подключена). Можно ли как-то решить этот вопрос при помоши Java? Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Ну и при чём тут Java?

Comment: @cy6erGn0m автор не знает разницы между Java и JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без серверной части при решении проблемы не обойтись никак.
Нашел сайт [zahodi-ka.ru](http://www.zahodi-ka.ru/wbmaster/floadc/)
Работу сервиса не проверял, но из его описания следует, что Вы получите счетчик загрузок, при этом серверный скрипт будет располагаться у них.
Если на указанном сайте неправда написана, то попробуйте посмотреть еще [здесь](http://www.google.com/?q=%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Answer (score 0):

Сдаётся мне, что автор имел ввиду другое... :-)
Если нужно считать общее количество переходов по ссылке всех пользователей и чтобы оно не сбрасывалось при каждом обновлении страницы, а где-то запоминалось - то тут одним только JavaScript не обойтись. Нужен серверный скрипт, который будет запоминать и сохранять. Например, написанный на PHP или Perl или ASP... Ну или каком-либо другом языке серверного программирования.